# inserting content with innerHTML doesn't execute <script> tags, can this be a security assumption?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using ajax to get content from php to update content on my page.
I want to know, since I insert the content using javascript innerHTML, is it necessary to check for script tags since, as far as I understand, script tags added with innerHTML won't run unless you intentionally evaluate them.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Say viewing comments for a post. User selects the post they wish to see, then I use ajax to load said post and comments. In one of the comments a user inserted a script tag with possibly harmful content, but since I update my page by using innerHTML (document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML= response;) the script tags won't be evaluated, as far as I know atleast, unless I specifically wrote something to evaluate them. So I was wondering is it worth worrying about it since this content will always be inserted using innerHTML and the script tags in them won't ever be evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

This should answer your question. If you want your script tags to be evaluated, you have to manually do it. If there is more code than just a script tag, then you will have to check for script tags.

There are ways around this, as shown in the example (putting script in the `onload` event in an empty tag) but you would have to change the content being retrieved from the server.

---

If you are scared that the client will insert harmful Javascript that will be executed, be scared! You should never do any senstive operations on the client side.

Comment: So you are saying I don't have to worry about security issues of harmful content in script tags as long as I insert them with innerHTML and don't have code on my page that will evaluate said inserted script tags?

Comment: No, script can be executed. If you look at the second answer to the question linked above, it is possible for code to be executed if it is in an event (this could be an `onload` or an `mouseover` etc). 

I would not recommend inserting code from another server that you don't trust like this. You could use frames but this might still leave your clients vulnerable.

Comment: There won't be any events on my page trying to evaluate the code inserted using innerHTML

Comment: Also, if it is user that is inserting html, you should sanitize this first. Furthermore, the client shouldn't be able to do anything harmful client side, this should be done on the server. Never trust the client!

Comment: @Ddrasheran what if the code inserted has an event? `<p onmouseover="alert('gotcha!')">Mouse over me!</p>`. The code in `onmouseover` would be evaluated when the client scrolls over it. The same could happen with `onload`.